# Как отключить подсказки пароля/логина на своём сайте?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, авторизация

Делаю веб приложение: [тут](http://playcaz.xyz)

Есть такая проблема:

Мой браузер (Хром) автоматически заполняет поля логина и пароля, меняя их background. Выглядит это не очень. Есть какой нибудь способ этого избежать?

[image: Скриншот]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть небольшой хак, можно сделать проще, но если хотите отключить для большинства браузеров, то используйте такой подход:

```
<form autocomplete="off">

  <!-- фейковые поля для chrome/opera -->
  <input id="username" style="display:none" type="text" name="fakeusernameremembered">
  <input id="password" style="display:none" type="password" name="fakepasswordremembered">

  <!--
    <input autocomplete="nope"> работает для всех полей кроме пароля
  -->
  <input id="real-username" type="text" autocomplete="nope">

  <!--
    <input type="password" autocomplete="new-password" отключит подстановку пароля для всех браузеров.
    -->
  <input id="real-password" type="password" autocomplete="new-password">

</form>
```